# Need InfoPath 2010 to automatically upgrade to new template

Tags: infopath

I have a form that was created in InfoPath 2010, as an InfoPath 2003 compatible form. It has managed code behind it (C#, InfoPath 2003 object model) and it is published directly to a SharePoint 2007 form library.  The form is opened from another application using XDocuments2.NewFromSolution.

I want users to automatically get the latest version of the form template, and that is what I have selected in the versioning option. However, those who are using InfoPath 2010 get a message when they open a new form after the template has been updated saying “Update Your Form” along with a button to “Save and Update Form.”

Here is what I have tried while trying to eliminate this:

1. Publishing as a site content type.
2. Publishing to a network location instead of to SharePoint.
3. Publishing to a network location and changing the form name (from this post http://www.infopathdev.com/forums/p/19260/66833.aspx)
4. Updating the version number to something totally new (like 2.0.0.1).

None of these work. This is a heavily used form and I don’t want anyone to get this Update message, especially because it makes the form not work correctly so it has to be closed and reopened. I need to figure this out before everyone is upgraded to Office 2010. It works fine in earlier versions of Office.

Does anyone have some other ideas I could try?

Thanks,
Beth

Answer (score 3):

I finally contacted Microsoft support and this is what I was told:

Unfortunately there is no way to avoid the InfoPath 2010 users getting that prompt to “Save and Update Form”.   Even with code it is not possible.
The users will only get the prompt the initial time to Save and Update Form as you already know, and then any subsequent openings will not prompt the users for any updates.  The only way around this option is to have the InfoPath 2010 users clear their InfoPath cache first, before accessing the forms.  This will delete the currently saved template information that is in their cache, so it will not prompt them to save and update the form since it doesn’t have any record of there being an open form.

The way to have users empty their InfoPath cache is by doing this:
Have them go to Start then either launch “Run” or in their “Start Search” bar (right above the Start button) have them type the following command:
   InfoPath  /cache clearall
(this will launch the InfoPath client on the user’s machine and they will now have empty InfoPath cache)

So I am going to make my form browser-enabled in order to avoid the Save and Update Form button.

Beth